# Typeorm complex query with promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I am getting data from multiple tables in typeorm like this :

```js
Order.findOne(orderId).then(order => {
  Stuff.findOne(order?.stuffId).then(stuff => {
    Site.findOne(stuff?.storeId).then(store => {
      Stuff.findOne(order?.stuffId).then(stuff1 => {
        Ware.findOne(stuff1?.wareId).then(ware => {
          Site.findOne(order?.unitId).then(unit => {
            Organization.findOne(order?.organizationId).then(
              organization => {
                // do some stuff with returned values       
              });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Now I know this is a bad code (too error-prone and confusing). I'm looking for a more convenient way to achieve this (getting multiple data from multiple tables) in typeorm.

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async function fectchAndExecute() {
  let order = await Order.findOne(orderId);
  let stuff = await Stuff.findOne(order ? .stuffId);
  let store = await Site.findOne(stuff ? .storeId);
  let ware = await Ware.findOne(stuff?.wareId);
  let unit = await Site.findOne(order?.unitId);
  let organization = await Organization.findOne(order?.organizationId);
  // do some stuff with returned values 
};
```

You can call this function.

Notice you do not need to name stuff as stuff1 again since you can use it already with stuff var.

Answer (score 2):

Using `async` and `await` will help deal with the level of nesting you have. Otherwise, if those queries don't depend on eachother, you can utilize `Promise.all` to execute those queries concurrently, e.g.

```
const [foo, bar, baz] = await Promise.all(fooQuery, barQuery, bazQuery)
```

Otherwise, if all those queries do depend on eachother in the order specified in your question, I'd examine how you've modelled your database and refactor appropriately.

Comment: thanks for reminding this ,its useful in another part of my code :)  but in the current problem some of the queries depend on other ones .

Comment: It's hard to diagnose how to fix this then without knowing the particularities of your schema. I'd look to refactor your tables such that you're able to do this work in SQL, whether that is through the TypeORM dsl or otherwise (e.g., take advantage of joins, denormalize your tables a bit, whatever).